# Ajax Combobox Text not being displaying in listbox visible area

Tags: asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajaxtoolkit for comboBox control for Autocomplete feature with .netframework 4.0. The version of AjaxControlToolkit.dll is 3.03053 and size is 4065 KB.

I am getting an issue of item displaying in its listbox area of combobox. I have more than 500 items in my datatable which is bind with combobox control through its DataSource property. When I type something in text area, corresponding item from list is being highlighted. But some time corresponding item not visible in list area, but item is still in list.

Please help me, if any body experiences this type of behavior. I am using IE9 and FireFox 15.0.1 Version.

```
<cc1:ComboBox ID="ddlAcntNameTest" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList"             AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="false" RenderMode="Inline" ItemInsertLocation="Append" CssClass="GreenTypeComboBoxStyle" ListItemHoverCssClass="" AutoPostBack="true" >  </cc1:ComboBox>
```

In Code Behind

```
  private void FillAcntNameTestDDL()
    {
            DataTable AccountList = NacWeb.LedgerAccount.GetAccountVisibleListForDdl();
            ddlAcntNameTest.DataSource = AccountList;
            ddlAcntNameTest.DataTextField = "AcntName";
            ddlAcntNameTest.DataValueField = "AcntId";
            ddlAcntNameTest.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must share the code in order to get a better idea. How we tell without looking at the code of the autocomplete and combo binding with the data source?

Well now after looking at the code I don't think there is a problem, you can try cleaning the solution and rebuilding the same.

go through the sample:[Combobox-sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: <cc1:ComboBox ID="ddlAcntNameTest" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
                                CaseSensitive="false" RenderMode="Inline" ItemInsertLocation="Append"
                                CssClass="GreenTypeComboBoxStyle" ListItemHoverCssClass="" AutoPostBack="true" >
                            </cc1:ComboBox>

Comment: @ Vinod...kindly edit the question and add the code there so that others can also answer. :)

Comment: The problem is that text that i am typing is not scroll in visible area of list box.